# Rewrite the absolute value of a rational function as a piecewise defined function

Tags: functions

How do I rewrite the function : $f(x)=\left|\frac{2x^5 - x^2 + 1}{x^2 - 4}\right|$ as a piecewise defined function?

The absolute value around both the numerator and the denominator is what's confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

Study the sign of each: the numerator and denominator. Decide under which conditions you will have to multiply the whole fraction by $-1$ (This is when one is positive and the other is negative), and under which conditions you should keep the fraction as it is (This will happen when one is negative and the other is positive). And you are done.